# ArrayFormula with IF Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to write an auto-expanding formula that tests if a value exists `Stakeholders/Communities` in column `D` on sheet `Elements` if it does write Yes in not write No

I have tried various thing, like

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(INDIRECT(Elements!D2:D="Stakeholders/Communities"),"Yes","No"))
```

But not getting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDIRECT("Elements!D2:D")="Stakeholders/Communities", "Yes", "No"))
```